# INTERSECT in mysql cant running

Tags: mysql

```
select 
   pengarang_id,buku_judul,penerbit_id
from buku 
left join bukupengarang on buku.penerbit_id = bukupengarang.pengarang_id 
INTERSECT
select 
pengarang_id,buku_judul,penerbit_id
from buku right join bukupengarang on buku.penerbit_id = bukupengarang.pengarang_id;`
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT
select pengarang_id,buku_judul,penerbit_id
from buku
right join bukup' at line 5

could anyone tell me whts problem here?
i dont understand abt this one, i just read it on inet n still didnt get it

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support the `INTERSECT` operator. You can emulate the `INTERSECT` operator in MySQL using join clauses.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/

It works with MariaDB since version 10.3.0.

Comment: so i should using "SELECT DISTINCT" for this case?

Comment: You can't emulate it?

Comment: can* typo sorry!

Comment: im not sure if i get it, :(